# PHP: Get the key from an array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

print_r($samplearr) prints the following for my array containing 3 items:

```
Array ( [4722] => Array ( [value1] => 52 [value2] => 46 )
Array ( [4922] => Array ( [value1] => 22 [value2] => 47 )
Array ( [7522] => Array ( [value1] => 47 [value2] => 85 )
```

I want to put these into an HTML table so I was doing a foreach but its not doing what I expected:

```
foreach($samplearr as $item){
     print "<tr><td>" . key($item) . "</td><td>" . $samplearr['value1'] . "</td><td>" . $samplearr['value2'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Which is returning:

```
<tr><td>value1</td><td>52</td><td>46</td></tr>
```

This would be the first output I am wanting:

```
<tr><td>4722</td><td>52</td><td>46</td></tr>
```

What function do I need to be using instead of key($item) to get the 4722?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($samplearr as $key => $item){
  print "<tr><td>" 
      . $key 
      . "</td><td>"  
      . $item['value1'] 
      . "</td><td>" 
      . $item['value2'] 
      . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: If you don't nedd $item. You could us `foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key){}`

Comment: ...or you could just store the reference `&$item` and not copy the variable, also sometimes retrieving array_keys is worse in performance than just going through it all "as is" :-)

Comment: Pls also see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Answer (score 4):

Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) with key and value.

Example:

```
foreach($samplearr as $key => $val) {
     print "<tr><td>" 
         . $key 
         . "</td><td>" 
         . $val['value1'] 
         . "</td><td>" 
         . $val['value2'] 
         . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you need nested foreach loops

```
foreach($samplearr as $key => $item){
   echo $key;
    foreach($item as $detail){
       echo $detail['value1'] . " " . $detail['value2']
     }
 }
```